# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component when login with auth0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a tutorial from https://auth0.com/blog/role-based-access-control-rbac-and-react-apps/ and it seems that author doesn't support it anymore.

The idea is simple: Once a user presses Login button (on Header.js) he is redirected to auth0 page. There he enters his data and is redirected back to localhost:3000/callback route. This is when `handleAuthentication` is triggered.

Unfortunately, I am facing an issue when setting the state when the `setSession` function is used.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Auth (created by App)
    in App
```

Here are the components:

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Auth from './Auth';
import  CallbackPage from "../pages/callback";

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Auth>
          <div style={{width: '1280px', margin: '0 auto'}}>
            <Router>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
                <Route path='/callback' component={CallbackPage} />
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </div>
      </Auth>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Auth.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';

import {AUTH_CONFIG} from '../auth0-variables';
import {AuthProvider} from '../authContext';

const auth = new auth0.WebAuth({
  domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
  clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
  redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
  audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
  responseType: 'token id_token'
});

class Auth extends Component {
  state = {
    authenticated: false,
  }

  initiateLogin = () => {
    auth.authorize();
  };

  handleAuthentication = () => {
    auth.parseHash((error, authResult) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(`Error ${error.error} occured`);
        return
      }
      this.setSession(authResult);
    })
  };

  setSession(authResult) {
    this.setState({
      // This does not update the state!!
      authenticated: true,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const authProviderValue = {
      ...this.state,
      initiateLogin: this.initiateLogin,
      handleAuthentication: this.handleAuthentication,
    };
    return (
      <AuthProvider value={authProviderValue}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthProvider>
    )
  }
};

export default Auth;
```

Header.js (Can component can be found at https://github.com/itaditya/react-rbac-auth0-article-code/blob/master/src/components/Can.js)

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Link }
from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from '../Login';
import Logout from '../Logout';
import Can from '../Can';
import { AuthConsumer } from '../../authContext';

const Header = (props) => {

  return (
    <AuthConsumer>
      {({ user }) => (
        <Can role={user.role} perform='home-page:seeLogin'
          yes={() => (
            <Login />
          )}
          no={() => (
            <Logout />
          )} 
        />
    </AuthConsumer>
  )
}

export default Header
```

And pages:
homePage:

```
import React from 'react';

const HomePage = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
    </div>
  )
};

export default HomePage;
```

Callback page

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import { AuthConsumer } from '../authContext';

const Callback = props => (
  <AuthConsumer>
    {({ handleAuthentication }) => {
      if (/access_token|id_token|error/.test(props.location.hash)) {
        handleAuthentication();
      }
      return <Redirect to='/' />;
    }}
  </AuthConsumer>
);

export default Callback;
```

Any help would be appreciated.